# IBM Watson Assistant chatbot not replying

Tags: websphere, chatbot, watson-assistant

I followed the modules in CognitiveAI "Build your own chatbot course" by IBM. I created an IBM Watson assistant chatbot, built intents, entities, and dialogs, but my chatbot has never replied back or responded to user input, it only detects the intents.
Please help to decipher what issue this might be and how I can rectify it

Comment: Add more details: How are you testing, e.g., using "Try it" or the webchat preview? Do you have created any responses? Any error or debug information on the detected intents?